# Swift actor pointing to a non sendable class

Tags: concurrency, actor, sendable

I am watching WWDC about actors and I don't understand something. Consider the following code

```swift
class ID: Hashable {
    var id: Int
    
    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: ID, rhs: ID) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

actor LibraryAccount {
    let id: ID
    var booksOnLoan: [Book]
    
    init(id: ID, booksOnLoan: [Book]) {
        self.id = id
        self.booksOnLoan = booksOnLoan
    }
}

extension LibraryAccount: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: LibraryAccount, rhs: LibraryAccount) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

extension LibraryAccount: Hashable {
    nonisolated func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
```

This code compiles with no warning with strict concurrency checking. The important thing here is of course that `ID` is a non-final class with `id` being a `var`, so definitely not sendable.

Suppose I call `==` on two instances of `LibraryAccount`, and they both have the same id. I read `ID.id` from the first, then another thread changes the id and then the `==` returns true, at which point the ids are already different.

Am I missing something here?